# Suma de importes por condición

Tags: mysql

Tengo un problema con una consulta:
Tengo este [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6fe20d/1).

La tabla `ctacte` almacena los movimientos por `cod`. El campo `flg` indica que: `+` se suman y los `-` se restan. Así se puede calcular el saldo por cada `cod`.

Con esto obtengo los saldos por `cod`:

```
SELECT cod,
SUM(CASE WHEN flg = '+' THEN importe ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN flg = '-' THEN importe ELSE 0 END) saldo
FROM ctacte
GROUP BY cod
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta ahí todo bien, pero ahora lo que necesito es que me muestre la suma de todos los saldos positivos:

```
SELECT cod,
SUM(CASE WHEN flg = '+' THEN importe ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN flg = '-' THEN importe ELSE 0 END) saldo
FROM ctacte
GROUP BY cod
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN flg = '+' THEN importe ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN flg = '-' THEN importe ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero el código anterior me muestra con los cod.
Solamente quiero que muestre la suma que sería 10 + 150 = **160**.
`cod` 22 no porque es negativo (-40).

**Solamente debe mostrar 160**.

Hice esto:

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN flg = '+' THEN importe ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN flg = '-' THEN importe ELSE 0 END) saldo
FROM ctacte
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN flg = '+' THEN importe ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN flg = '-' THEN importe ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

Pero me muestra **120** y es porque suma y resta todos los cod.
Cómo puedo filtrar para que solamente me muestre la suma de los saldos positivos que sería **160**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haz de tu consulta una subconsulta para sumar los resultados:

```
SELECT sum(saldo)
  FROM ( SELECT cod
              , SUM(if(flg='-',-1,1)*importe) saldo
           FROM ctacte
           GROUP BY cod
       ) tmp
  WHERE saldo > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

No se ...
solo tienes que quitar la resta ¿no?

```sql
SELECT cod,
SUM(CASE WHEN flg = '+' THEN importe ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN flg = '-' THEN importe ELSE 0 END) saldo,
SUM(CASE WHEN flg = '+' THEN importe ELSE 0 END)  "saldo positivo"
FROM ctacte
GROUP BY cod
```

¿Es eso lo que buscas?

Comment: Es que así va a considerar todos los cod. Lo que se necesita es que no considere los cod cuyo saldo sea negativo..

Comment: he dejado la linea original y la de abajo le falta la parte donde no considera los codigos con flg -

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta, explicando mejor.